# Move an input into a form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to move an element inside a form and then change the display to block. I am getting the display to change but can't seem to move it, this is the code I am using

```
<form action="testsubmit.php">
    <div id="placehere">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<div id="input1" style="display:none">
<input type="text" name="test" id="input1">
</div>

<button onclick="test()">Click me</button>


<script>
function test(){
    document.getElementById('input1').appendChild(document.getElementById('placehere'));
    document.getElementById('input1').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Its working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/6qxurbuw/

Comment: Your code works fine, are you trying to display the field next to the button by any chance?

Comment: Not quite, it needed to be above the submit button, I had the id's the wrong way round

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the insertion  has to be done in the other way round

```
document.getElementById('placehere').appendChild(
     document.getElementById('input1')
);
```

The DOM insertion via `appendChild()` is in fact `<parentNode>.appendChild(<node>)`

Then, to show the element javascript is not necessary. just hide the `input` by default via CSS, and show it when it is inside the `form` element

```
#input1 { display: none }
#placehere #input1 { display: block }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
     document.getElementById('placehere').appendChild(document.getElementById('input1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<form action="testsubmit.php">
    <div id="placehere"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<div style="display:none">
<input type="text" name="test" id="input_text">
</div>

<button onclick="test()">Click me</button>


<script>
function test(){
    document.getElementById('placehere').appendChild(document.getElementById('input_text'));
    document.getElementById('input_div').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```